# How to use psd elements in an upload form?

Tags: html, css, psd

so I have come across an upload template I can use for my site, however I have absolutely no idea on where to start. I want the the template that I have (shown below) to be exactly like it is but on the site and fully functional, how would I do this?

[image]

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: This is done by using simple css styles, for example, to create a button like the "done" button in the image below, we would simply create the shape first,

```
background-color: #000; /*change this to a color of your liking*/
width: 100px;
height: 70px;
```

this will create the rectangle like figure that we would want.

Now, we can create the cornered edges by applying these;

```
border-radius: 2px; /*change this to your liking*/
```

And that's how to create a button similar to the ones below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should strip the complete image in very tiny parts. For example; the cancel button should be split in a 1px,1px square (repeat it in the css) and convert it to .PNG or if possible take only the css from it, right click on the layer -> copy css.

To avoid high loading or huge broadband usage, you should not take the whole image and put it on your website. This will also not be responsive friendly, if you would like to make it responsive.